# is it possible? how to access node.js file from different node.js file in different directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, export

It might be a simple but unable to crack it. started learning node.js. i want to use password-manager.js file in test.js. how can i do this.

**

```
My Directory structure:-
    root
        -home 
           - node-basics
               - node-password
                   - password-manager.js
               -node-mongo-connection
                   -test.js
```

**

```
//In password-manager.js
module.exports = function(){
//code.......

}



//I tried to module.exports
// test.js
var pm = require('/../../password-manager.js');
//but not sure doing it correctly or its a correct  method or not.
```

Comment: Try `require('../node-password/password-manager')`

Comment: @vibhor1997a thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relative path to `password-manager.js` is wrong.

Use this:

```
 var pm = require('../node-password/password-manager');
```